# Java generic concept

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to create a generic class with a method that accepts a generic parameter. Now in another class create a method that will accept an object of that generic class. and call the generic method from new/main class. like below sample code.

```
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainClass gp = new MainClass();
        Class1<Integer> cls1=new Class1<>();
        gp.method1(cls1);
    }
    
    public void method1(Class1<? extends Number> obj2) {
        obj2.method(10);  //CT error - can't pass integer
    }
}

class Class1<T> {
    public void method(T arg) {
        
    }
}
```

I am getting compile time error. I am learning generic. I don't know where I am missing?

Comment: And ... what do you want to know?

Comment: @ElHoss I am getting Compile Time error.

Comment: `? extends Number` could be `Float`. You can't just pass in an Integer. `? super Number` would work though.

Comment: obj2 is a an object of any class parameterized with any class that extends Number. It can by Double, Integer, BigDecimal etc. So the error is ok - Integer may not fit.

Comment: Go through this [Oracle Java Tutorial on Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html) first. Then, come back here and refine your question with specifics or simply close the question.

Comment: @user16320675 Just research _Java PECS_.

Comment: @user16320675 so that you could answer your own observation.

Comment: @user16320675 Never mind. This questions is closed now for the same reason why I told you to research PECS.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. If you want your class to hold any Number, use `Class1<Number>`. If you want specifically Integers, why would you use `Class1<? extends Number>`?

Comment: @user16320675 no, I made the comment before I saw it was closed. Anyway, I thought you were bringing the point because of some confusion. I realize now that it was more rhetorical than anything else. Point taken.